# Text formatting on pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pymongo

I am creating a dataframe and then converting that dataframe into a pivot table. The text and the column headers in the pivot table are aligned to center in my result. I would like to set the text justify as "left". Could you please help with this ? I've tried `df.to_string(justify = 'true')` but it throws an attribute error that `"'Unicode' object has no attribute 'columns'"`

This is my dataframe:

```
df = DataFrame({'Customer': CustomerCOL,'Title': titleCOL,'count':countCOL})
table = pivot_table(df,index = ['Customer','Title'],values='count')
```

Comment: What do you mean by `text` exactly? Can you post the output you don't like and try to show the output you want? Your explanation is not really enough to give you an answer.

Comment: Hi joe, by text I mean the data in the excel cells. For eg: After I convert the dataframe to pivot table. I am writing the data back to excel. On the excel side, the justification or the alignment of the data is "center". I want to align the data to "left". Does this help ? I am trying to attach a sample data with current and expected output but I don't see an option for attachment here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need set parameter `justify` to `left` in [`to_string`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer': ['Ann Green', 'Joseph Smith', 'Ann Green'],
                'Title': ['Ms', 'Mr', 'Ms'],
                'count':[4, 6, 7]})
print (df) 
       Customer Title  count
0     Ann Green    Ms      4
1  Joseph Smith    Mr      6
2     Ann Green    Ms      7

table = pd.pivot_table(df,index = ['Customer','Title'],values='count').reset_index()
print (table)
       Customer Title  count
0     Ann Green    Ms    5.5
1  Joseph Smith    Mr    6.0

print (table.to_string(justify = 'left'))
  Customer      Title  count
0     Ann Green  Ms    5.5  
1  Joseph Smith  Mr    6.0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, "display.colheader_justify" to left is applicable just for column headers not the actual data.

Comment: Hey thanks again, I tried that but running into this error   " if len(to_filter) < len(data.columns):
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'columns'"

Comment: Also, I am writing the pivot table data back to excel by doing this writer = ExcelWriter("FilePath"+ ".xlsx")
table.to_frame("").to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Sheet1"
writer.save()

Comment: Problem is with my test data in answer or with your real data?

Comment: Problem is with my real data.